# Save password or type every time: which way is safer?

Tags: security, browser, passwords

Now most browsers support remembering passwords for sites. But I always have prefered to typing them every time, since I thought it was safer, until today when I start to contemplate if it's really safer.

I think the passwords stored in browsers are not completely safe. For example, in MS Edge I can manage the password I saved and actually unveil them. In addition, if MS Edge generates a new password for a site I never logged in on the browser, it also will show the password to me. So I have always thought that if there's some program (suppose that my computer has the possibility of being screen recorded) that can read the screen and convert it to text then it's very vulnerable.

For typing passwords of course a keyboard logger can simply expose it. And the more I type, the probability of it getting logged by some logger is bigger (suppose that my computer has the possibility of being logged).

Given these of my thoughts, I can't decide which way is safer for me. Which way is safer?

I appreciate your answers and time in advance.

P.S. I think posting it here is better than posting it on information security stack exchange. If I'm wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always considered the issue to be remembering 200 different, sufficiently secure passwords without using a guessable pattern that could be easily hacked. [That's why enforced periodic password changes on corporate structures are not recommended - people write them down or use simple patterns.]

If you have malware you already have a bigger problem.

If you lose control of your physical computer, then your security is as strong as your main access password, firmware lock & encryption protocols.

Also see: https://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: Thanks. Now I know I should worry more about the problems you mentioned.